# Re-install system for another pc

Tags: system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu on another PC without losing personal files, installed software, configuration, etc...

Here is the situation:

I have Ubuntu installed on `ssd` of my laptop.

I'm buying a new laptop and I just want to replace `ssd` from my old laptop to a new one and somehow reinstall system/drivers and have a working OS on my new laptop.

My current laptop system is configured the way I want it, and I just don't want to go through Installing Ubuntu  again?

I couldn't find anything related,How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

My advice is backup all personal files and configurations to an external hard disk and make a fresh install on your new laptop and then copy the files to it.

If you just change the disk, your old configurations will be used in your new hardware. This might be a problem if your new system has a different graphics board, just to start.

But you can allways try the disk on the new laptop and see what happens (as long as you backup first).

Personally, I put all the files I really need on a service like Dropbox, this way even if I loose the disk, I just have to install Dropbox and all my files get copied to disk again.